# Redirect http subdomain to https

Tags: nginx, http, redirect, https, subdomain

I'm trying to redirect all requests from http://blog.example.org to https://blog.example.org.

Unfortunately I receive this error:

```
400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

My config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name blog.example.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
}


server {
    server_name blog.example.org;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    root /srv/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

Comment: What is the complete nginx configuration? What does nginx `error.log` tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement is incorrect. You should have:

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure, but I think the use of `$is_args` and `$args` is wrong here as `$request_uri` would contain the full request string (full URI path with arguments). Have you tried without those? Eg:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.example.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect block should be:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name blog.example.org;
    return 301 https://blog.example.org$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using rewrite, instead of return.

```
rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
```

That's how it's done on our server. It may be a deprecated method, since it's been like this forever, but it works on nginx 1.10.0

edit: I was looking at the wrong problem. You need to add these directives to your ssl server configuration:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/public/certificate.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/private/key.pem;
```